# How do I make a patch from a github repo if I failed to make a feature branch?

Tags: git, github, patch, rebase, apache-whirr

I forked/cloned apache whirr on Github, and began work on the trunk branch. During the work, I pulled two commits from origin/trunk. When I generate a patch by running a git diff first_feature_commit HEAD, I get a patch that has these two commits in it. The patch was therefore rejected when I submitted it.

How do I create a patch without the commits that I pulled from origin/trunk?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the patch using `git format-patch` and it will split them up.  You could also just make your diff with `git diff HEAD^` to get only your commit (which is presumably the most recent one).

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b rj/rilly_feature
git rebase -i master
# remove spurious commits in interactive rebase file
git diff master
# observe success
```

This is intended to address your "failure" to create a feature branch—if you think you should be working from a feature branch, this will get you on one and allow you to generate a clean patch too.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said `git diff`, that will be empty in that case. Can you generate the patch you want, though? With `git diff master`?

Comment: The rebase is a noop. Git diff master generates nothing.

Comment: Does that mean that creating a branch and rebasing discarded your changes? Or what is in `git log`?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a remote to the repository you are interested in patching. Probably something like

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/apache/whirr.git
```

2) Fetch the remote. Just get all of them probably:

```
git fetch --all
```

3) Make your patch!

```
git diff upstream/trunk..HEAD >my.patch
```

HTH!
@eldondev

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get only those commits that are in your master branch and not on `origin/master` (the server) you can get those with

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

For more details please see [Git Tools - Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) of Pro Git.